# SUMO_HOME ... the mystery continues

Tags: bashrc

I'm running Ubuntu 17.10.1 and have downloaded sumo 0.32.0 from the Ubuntu respository via Synaptic.  Configuration instructions assert that SUMO_HOME should be set in the "base directory" of the installation, adding that this directory contains the subdirectories "bin" and "tools." While as search shows a tools subdirectory located in "/usr/share/sumo/tools/contributed/traas/src/de/tudresden/sumo," there certainly is no "bin" subdirectory.  Bottom line, I have attempted to set the SUMO_HOME environmental variable to /usr/bin/sumo, usr/share/sumo, and  /usr/share/doc/sumo/examples/sumo -- all with the same results ... SUMO_HOME not found.  If not in any of these locations, where?

Answer (score 1):

According to [official documentation](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Basics/Basic_Computer_Skills#Using_a_pre-packaged_version_of_SUMO) for pre-packaged SUMO the following setting is correct:

```
export SUMO_HOME=/usr/share/sumo
```

If it works, then you can add it to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`.

Please note, that examples are located in */usr/share/doc/sumo-doc* and available from `sumo-doc` package.

You can start `sumo-gui` with simple hello network */usr/share/doc/sumo-doc/tutorial/hello/data/hello.netccfg* .

Comment: To make it apply on a global scale, OP should add `SUMO_HOME='/usr/share/sumo'` to `/etc/environment` and then reboot.  This way the entire system gets that variable available, not just the single individual's singular session.